# where is the Source code of adadelta in Tensorflow？

Tags: python, optimization, tensorflow

recently I have some confusion about adadelta in `TensorFlow`，I want to modify it rules of learning-rate ，but i not know how to do it.
i think i have to modify the source code :
because the rules is encapsulated in `train.AdadeltaOpertimizer`，and the class not
return learning-rate,it only has a initially learning-rate:

def **init**(self, learning_rate=0.001, rho=0.95, epsilon=1e-8,
               use_locking=False, name="Adadelta"):

where is the source code of adadelta in Tensorflow？

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/17c47804b86e340203d451125a721310033710f1/tensorflow/python/training/adadelta.py

Answer (score 0):

I have not understood what exactly you want to modify, so I will just show how to find the source code for everything.

Each function in TF has information about the source-code of this function in the documentation. It points you to the python file.

For example [AdaDelta optimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/AdadeltaOptimizer) has this in the docs:

> Defined in [tensorflow/python/training/adadelta.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/training/adadelta.py#L27).

Comment: After your comments, I went to see the source code of TensorFlow, but I did not find where the adadelta's formula.Some functions are defined in adadelta.py,such as:_apply_dense(self, grad, var),and then,I enter the function of training_ops.apply_adadelta() and enter apply_op() from apply_adadelta().Finally,I find the return 'op'.I think the 'op' is the function's   (_apply_dense()) output.But where is the algorithmic formula.

Comment: For your question, you can refer to this example: adadelta calculated after a learning rate - r, I have to make such a change: r + c. So, I need to find the source part of the formula that implements this algorithm.